# calc results into html

Tags: javascript, html, output, calculation

Im trying to write a javascript code that will do the following.
Get values from several `<select>` lists in a seperate html file. Then do the following using javascript

```
var one=A*B*C+A*D+E+A;
var two= one/C;
```

Then print `var two` under the html form.

Comment: You must add more context and precisions to your question.

Comment: `...in a seperate html file.`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got it, your question is not really clear...
I believe you should declare an id for your "select" in HTML and use this to print the result.

```
selectid.innerHTML = `${two}`
```